# Is it possible to strip Spree of its default styling and layout and start from scratch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I need to build an e-commerce website, and was looking at Spree Commerce to take care of my back-end. However, tailoring it to look exactly how I want it seems difficult. It comes with all this pre-made styling and layout that I have to *override* and *change*. I'd rather just strip it of all its default styling and layout and create the front-end myself.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming [the documentation](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html) is correct, you can just copy some (all?) of the view templates into your application and tweak them to your heart's content.

> For example, to override the main layout, create the file YOUR_SITE_OR_EXTENSION/app/views/spree/layouts/spree_application.html.erb

I think you'll be in for some significant work, though.

Answer (score 0):

The Spree Way is to use [Deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) and override the defaults views and layouts if you need changes in the HTML structure, for all presentational changes use CSS. Wny? Because when you update Spree for a newer version the work will be less than create the new front-end yourself. It's not so complicated and you can take advantage of the Spree Extensions.

But as @james-mason mentioned you can create new views and layouts for replacing the defaults.